# Using Expression Blend 4 with Visual Studio2010 for debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, expression-blend-4

I'm doing my views implementation in `Blend 4` and I want to debug my code in `Visual Studio 2010`.

After start my project from Blend I attach the VS debugger to it. The debugging works fine.
The next time I want to debug again (after some modifications) I can't build the project with error message:

`Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\Application.exe" to "bin\Debug\Application.exe". The process cannot acess the file "bin\Debug\Applicaiton.exe" because it is being used by another process`

The same message comes from both dev.app.

According to the Task Manager there is no running Application.exe.
When I close the Visual Studio I can run the project again.

What is the solution to run and modify and debug the code without always reopening one of these dev.apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete your obj/bin folders, that stuff is created when built. Personally what I do is all my view work in Blend, then I always build from VS. As long as you have all your SDK's and everything is synced etc I found this to be the best way.

Just remember to ctrl+Shift+S often when you're flipping between Blend & VS or you'll find that the contents of one may overwrite the other by mistake.

So for example if I do some view/design work in Blend, I religiously save it, then flip over to VS to build it. The only down side to this, is you need a decent spec machine to run both Blend & VS simultaneously without much lag. Hope this helps.